# Could not refresh the webform - Sorry, the action could not be completed. Please contact the administrator if the error persists

Tags: oracle-bpm-suite

After creating web form in Oracle BPM Composer I am facing below issue

***Could not refresh the webform - Sorry, the action could not be completed. Please contact the administrator if the error persists***

Exception is

oracle.bpm.composer.exception.editor.WebFormControllerException: oracle.bpm.webform.exception.WebFormsException: Error reaching form service.
....
Caused by: com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Bad Request
Could not process API POST for /frevvo/web/tn/designer/api/doctypes: null